scaling ol-overlay point while zooming map in vue3-openlayers
I position some points on a map via ol-overlay, strangely the points do not scale as intended, they should scale with the zoom of the map.
<div class="map-container">
       
        <ol-map style="height:980px" >
            <ol-view ref="viewRef" :center="center" :enableRotation="enablerotation" :rotation="rotation" :zoom="zoom" :maxZoom="maxZoom" :minZoom="minZoom" :projection="projection" :extent="extent" :smoothExtentConstraint="true" :showFullExtent="true" :smoothResolutionConstraint="true" @zoomChanged="onZoomChanged"  @resolutionChanged="onResolutionChanged"/>
           
            
            <ol-overlay :position="pos.pos" positioning="center-center" v-for="pos, index in position" :key="index">
                <template v-slot="slotProps">
                    <div class="marker" :xxx="slotProps" @click="doPoint(pos.targetnr)">{{ pos.targetnr }}</div>
                </template>
            </ol-overlay>


            <ol-image-layer>
              
                <ol-source-image-static :url="imgUrl" :imageSize="size" :imageExtent="imageExtent" :projection="projection"></ol-source-image-static>
            </ol-image-layer>

        </ol-map>

    </div>

